# Difference between "dialect" and "accent"

Tags: differences

Please I want to know the difference between the two words( dialect and accent)

Comment: What the others said.  But it's not a hard-and-fast division but rather a continuous spectrum -- a mildly different dialect might be noticeable only as an "accent", plus maybe an occasional difference in word choice.  While a strong "accent" can sound like another language.

Answer (score 1):

An accent is all about the pronunciation of words. English speakers in Ireland, Scotland, Wales, England, Canada, USA, Australia, New Zealand, India and Pakistan can all understand understand one another, but the differences in how the speakers from each country pronounce words, or the sounds that make up the English language is called an accent of each country.

A dialect arises when different groups of people who speak the same language use words that the other group or groups do not use.

Answer (score 0):

Dialect is a variation of a language e.g. In Brazil, a colony of Italian-descendants speaks a dialect that is close to Italian, but in fact it has many differences.

While an accent is the way that people that live in a particular region speak, toning a few more sounds than people that live in other region would do.